# Setting AssemblyFileVersion isn't working

Tags: c#

I would like to set my assembly file version as follows: **6.0.ddMMyy.build number** but it doesn't seem to be working and I think it's caused by the version number only accepting certain values.

Example:

```
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("6.0.100213.1")]
```

This results in the following version number whenever the assembly is compiled:

```
6.0.34677.1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

100213 - 34677 = 65536.  A magic number, 2^16 and ushort.MaxValue.  The 4 parts of the version number must have a value between 0 and 65535.

Another convention to store the build date is to pick an arbitrary date 0 and count the number of hours or days since that date.  Which is what Microsoft does.  .NET 2.0 is version 2.0.50727 with date 0 at 1/1/2000.  new DateTime(2000, 1, 1) + TimeSpan.FromHours(50727) = October 14th 2005, 3 pm.

Comment: I'd like to have a date that makes sense and that doesn't require me getting out my calculator but this does answer the question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the value (100213) is being manipulated by the compiler when it creates the build number. The limit is a 16 bit value. This [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2007/01/03/why-are-build-numbers-limited-to-65535.aspx) describes the bug / issue.